# Numlock disables itself after use

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, input, numlock

Ever since I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS my numlock does not work the way it should. Everytime I enable it, press one of the numlock keys, it disables itself. Can I make this behaviour stop somehow?

Thanks in advance!

-TheBoneJarmer